# Put Text as Background of a SeekBar in Android

Tags: android, text, seekbar

I want to put a Text as `Background` of a `SeekBar`, attached image to explain it, but I can not do it, I can only put images.

[image]

Anyone know tell me the correct way to do it?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place two views on top of each other. (internationalization wont be so easy using images)

For example using a frame layout, your views will always be stacked. Or you could use a relative layout and align all edges of each child with the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the draable of the seekBar and the background :
You can put your text in some of your drawbles

```
 <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_line"
            android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
            android:thumbOffset="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/seekbar_bg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same thing that you are. Here's my method :

```
Bitmap btmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sb.getWidth(), sb.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(btmap);
c.drawText(Text, 0, sb.getHeight()/2, null);
LayerDrawable background = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{new BitmapDrawable(btmap)});
sb.setBackground(background);
```

Hope this helps